# What fields do I need in my spreadsheets to get started?

Tags: fields

I'm with a small non-profit that publishes a magazine and receives donations. There are separate spreadsheets for subscribers and donors, with a big overlap between.
In preparing the spreadsheets for conversion to CiviCRM, what fields must I have?

Comment: Hi Polly - that is a really hard question to answer without lots more information about what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps just spend some time in civicrm familiarising yourself, set up some test contacts, add the data that makes sense. Then you could do an Export and compare that with your spreadsheets.

Comment: I find it can also be helpful to copy just the column titles (or also a couple of rows of data) and paste TRANSPOSED so i have it all in columns - may just be me, but i find it easier to run my eyes down the column of titles, than having to read left-to-right (not sure i am explaining this well without an example)

Comment: Finally - if you did the above and wanted to share as eg a Google S/sheet then I would be happy to take a quick look and add some comments if that was any help.